# Building Spring using Gradle - error with referencePdf task

Tags: spring, build, gradle

I'm running the build.gradle script that comes with the 3.2.6 RELEASE zip file.  I have made no changes to that file.  I've installed Gradle 1.9 locally.  When running the script, I get the following error:

```
:referencePdf FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':referencePdf'.
> Unable to delete file: C:\Downloads\SpringSource\spring-framework-3.2.6.RELEASE\build\reference\pdf\images\note.png

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to
get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 44.264 secs
Stopping 1 Gradle compiler daemon(s).
Process 'Gradle Worker 1' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
Stopped 1 Gradle compiler daemon(s).
```

Since I'm running Gradle on Win 7 64 bit, I've updated the folder Gradle has a problem with so that everyone has full access rights to the folder.  Even still, the Gradle script fails to complete successfully.  I'm new to Gradle and really don't know how the build.gradle script works.  Any tips as to what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to run the build via the checked-in `gradlew` script, rather than your local Gradle installation. This makes sure that you run with the Gradle version that's required for building this project.

On Windows, there can sometimes be problems deleting files when using the daemon. Try and delete the `build` folder manually. If the problem comes back, consider running without the Gradle daemon, e.g. by passing `--no-daemon`.

Comment: When I downloaded spring-framework-3.2.6.RELEASE.zip from Git, did that not included the "checked in gradlew script"?

Comment: I tried deleting the build folder and running with --no-daemon, and I get the same error.

Comment: If I run the build with "-x referencePDF", it does complete without an error.

Comment: Try to kill all daemons first.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows at the command prompt run: `gradlew referencePdf --stacktrace` and that should tell you what happened. In my case, it was a heap size issue. I set an environment variable `set GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"` then was able to build the pdf successfully.